# PHP how to access object dynamicly?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've got the following object:

```
$json = '{"response": {"status": {"message": "Success"}, "images": [{"url": "http://domain.com/images/0001.jpg"}, {"url": "http://domain.com/images/0001.jpg"}]}}'; 
$obj  = json_decode($json);
```

Then i have an array:

```
$obj_path = array('response', 'images');
```

I can access `images` within `$obj` like so `$obj->$obj_path[0]->$obj_path[1]` 
 **How would i do it more dynamically? Something along the line of...**

```
$obj_path_count = count($obj_path);
for($i=0; $i<$obj_path_count; $i++)
{
   $obj_access_path .= '->' . $obj_path[$i]; //Build path to the access the object?
}
var_dump($obj . $obj_access_path); // Display object images
```

The above code gives the following error

> Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string

Comment: What exactly is the point of doing it dynamically, in your case? Do you want to access variables by a variable name (`$$varName`)? Do you want to create more concise code? Or make decisions on which array item to pick?

Comment: I've got number of objects and an array of the items i need to grab. Guess i am after more concise code which lets me pick the elements of the object that are defined in an array

Comment: By the way, the . in `var_dump` should be a comma, I believe, whence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access a full path like that, the interpolation only goes one level deep. You can do something like this though:

```
$obj_access = $obj;
foreach($obj_path as $path_item)
{
   $obj_access = $obj_access->$path_item;
}
var_dump($obj_access); // Display object images
```

Looking at your JSON though, I don't think this will help fix whatever problem it is you are trying to solve however.